# Ubuntu 12.04 - I can ssh into the server but sshd is an unrecognized service

Tags: 12.04, ssh, services

I'm trying to setup key based authentication for ssh on my Ubuntu 12.04 server following [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty) tutorial and [that](http://adamwright.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/ssh-error-server-refused-our-key-and-how-to-fix-it/).

It's not really working but I have another problem slowing me down, which is that I can't restart the ssh service.

I can ssh to the server without any trouble. If I do `ps aux | grep -i "ssh"` I can see the sshd process but if I do `service sshd restart` then I get "sshd unrecognized service". I can restart ssh but I take it that's a client, not a server.

If I Google "sshd unrecognized service" I get to know all about troubleshooting ssh connectivity but that's not my problem.

I tried purging and reinstalling openssh-server, to no effect.

How can I restart the sshd service if that service doesn't exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SSH server service in Ubuntu is named "ssh". Just run `sudo service ssh restart` to restart it.

Comment: This may be true of Debian in general. It's the case in Raspbian Jessie.